# Find the next Transform to the left or right of a Player

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, coroutine

I have a class that has a public array of transforms which are points a character can move to. Every time the player hits either the A or D key their character will smoothly move to the next position either to the left or right depending on if they hit A or D.

The way I am attempting this is to Start a Coroutine when the player hits the A or D key on the keyboard. The coroutine will then immediately find the next left Transform point in the array and begin to move there using a while loop.

Now the problem I am having is being able to find the closest left/right point.. How would I go about doing this?

Here is my code so far:

```c#
public Transform[] positions;

    public int StartPosition = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        //set the start position, change the index to the one you would like the player to start at
        transform.position = positions[StartPosition].position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Register Key Events
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move("Left", transform.position));
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move("Right", transform.position));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the player character to the next position to the left or right
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerator Move(string dir, Vector2 currentPosition)
    {
        if(dir == "Left")
        {
            //Find and store next left position if it exists
            // HOW DO I DO THIS??????

            // Go To Next Left Position
            while (transform.position.x > nextLeftPos.position.x)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextLeftPos.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                //Come back next frame
                yield return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

And here is my player movement component:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this test by using the `Transform.right` vector, which points to the right of the player.

By creating a unit vector from the player to the position, and substracting the `Transform.forward` vector, you will get a vector that allows you to test whether the point is at the left side or at the right side of the player.

```
Vector3 f = transform.forward;
Vector3 r = transform.right;
foreach (Transform t in Positions) {
    Vector3 pos = t.position;
    Vector3 sideTest = (pos - f).normalized;

    if(Vector3.Dot(sideTest, r)) >= 0.0) {
        // This position its on the right
    } else {
        // This position is on the left
    }
}
```

It would be more efficent to pre-compute all this information into a tree before start the game, as you can get the next 2 positions to test instead of looping over all the array.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your positions are not will be changed during the game session.

Create an integer as the player position. Take the middle of the screen as start point and forget about your player's current transform.position. Count position in the array.

For example; if your player staying on the thirdth element of array. Then move right should be to the fourth one. So fourth element position is already defined in the array as Transform.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgnNp.png)

Rough script is here;

```
 public int whichRoad;
    public float roadChangeSpeed = 5.0f;
    Vector2 roadMinusOne = new Vector2(-2.4f, -3.44f); // -1. Left road coordinates
    Vector2 roadZero = new Vector2(0f, -3.44f);       // 0.  Middle road coordinates
    Vector2 roadOne = new Vector2(2.44f, -3.44f);      // 1. Right road coordinates
    Vector2 choosenRoad;


void SwipeLeft(){

bla bla bla swipe left
whichRoad--;

}

void SwipeRight(){

bla bla bla swipe right
whichRoad++;

}

void FixedUpdate()
{

ChangeRoad();
}


    void ChangeRoad() 
        {
            if (whichRoad == -1)

            {

              choosenRoad = roadMinusOne;

            }

            else if (whichRoad == 0)

            {

                choosenRoad = roadZero;

            }

            else if (whichRoad == 1)

            {

                choosenRoad = roadOne;

            }


                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, choosenRoad, Time.deltaTime * roadChangeSpeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use while loop to check this, as the performance is very low in general. The suggested way is to use Raycast and collider.

[image]

Add sphere colliders to all the "points", i.e. candidate game objects to collide with the current player, and use below snippet:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 left = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left);

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, left, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.position); // <--- this is what you want
    }
}
```

A good tutorial can be found [here](http://devblog.aliasinggames.com/raycastall-unity/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I have found a solution that combines using movement flags in `Update()` as well as `Vector3.MoveTowards()`. In order to stop the player once he reaches his next destination point I have a function that is called after every move call which detects if the player is coming into contact with any of the movement points in the array. If so, it sets the movement flags to false and stores the players current position index.

Here is my class:

```c#
public class PlayerMovementStepper : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Tooltip("From furthest left to furthest right...")]
        public Transform[] Points;

        [Tooltip("How fast the player moves between points")]
        public float MoveSpeed;

        [Tooltip("On which point index does the player start?")]
        public int StartPointIndex;

        //This is going to be so we can tell which point to move towards
        private int currentIndex;

        //Moving flags for update function
        private bool movingLeft = false;
        private bool movingRight = false;

        private void Awake()
        {
            transform.position = Points[StartPointIndex].position;
            currentIndex = StartPointIndex;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            //Check for movement flags
            if (movingLeft)
            {
                if (currentIndex > 0)
                {
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Points[currentIndex - 1].position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                StopPlayerIfOnPoint();
            }

            if (movingRight)
            {
                if (currentIndex < Points.Length - 1)
                {
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Points[currentIndex + 1].position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                StopPlayerIfOnPoint();
            }
        }

        public void MoveToNextLeft()
        {
            movingLeft = true;
            movingRight = false;
        }

        public void MoveToNextRight()
        {
            movingLeft = false;
            movingRight = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This Function calls after every move call (if any) to check
        /// whether or not the player hit the next point. If the player did hit 
        /// then it will stop the player from moving and then store its current 
        /// position.
        /// </summary>
        private void StopPlayerIfOnPoint()
        {
            var i = 0;
            foreach (Transform pos in Points)
            {
                //Check for collisions
                if (transform.position == pos.position)
                {
                    if (movingLeft || movingRight)
                    {
                        currentIndex = i;
                    }
                    movingLeft = false;
                    movingRight = false;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
```

This class allows the user to attach multiple position points the player can move to as long as they add them from furthest left to furthest right:

[image]

I would like all the input I can get for this solution. One thing I notice I will need to change right away is the way I detect when the player has reached his next destination point. Right now it is relying on the player character being Exactly in position with a point in the points array. I would rather have the destination point stored in a variable and while the character is moving I could possibly check if the player is within a certain radius of the point in order to stop it and snap the player to that point.

Anyway. Let me know what you all think. Thanks in advance.